# Received an exception FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index

Tags: android, firebase, google-cloud-firestore

I create the project in firebase using a cloud database and I want to compare `empUID` field which store in a document with current `UID`.

I created one query which gets the data when current `UID` and `empUID` is match but failed to get data.

Please guide is my Query right or am I need to changes in my code

**MY Subcollection Path**

> Employer(root Collection)-->Job Post(Sub collection)-->Job Applicant
>   Details(sub collection of Job post)

**Logcat**

```
2020-02-10 10:38:36.239 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job I/Adreno: Build Config                     : S P 6.0.7 AArch64
2020-02-10 10:38:36.231 29836-29836/com.example.part_time_job W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:9359): avc: denied { search } for name="proc" dev="debugfs" ino=16085 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c183,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-02-10 10:38:36.242 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job I/Adreno: PFP: 0x016ee180, ME: 0x00000000
2020-02-10 10:38:36.231 29836-29836/com.example.part_time_job W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:9360): avc: denied { search } for name="ctx" dev="debugfs" ino=16114 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c183,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-02-10 10:38:36.245 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasWideColorDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-02-10 10:38:36.245 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job I/ConfigStore: android::hardware::configstore::V1_0::ISurfaceFlingerConfigs::hasHDRDisplay retrieved: 0
2020-02-10 10:38:36.245 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job D/libEGL: eglInitialize: exit(res=1)
2020-02-10 10:38:36.245 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job I/OpenGLRenderer: Initialized EGL, version 1.4
2020-02-10 10:38:36.246 29836-29895/com.example.part_time_job D/OpenGLRenderer: Swap behavior 2
2020-02-10 10:38:36.241 29836-29836/com.example.part_time_job W/RenderThread: type=1400 audit(0.0:9361): avc: denied { search } for name="ctx" dev="debugfs" ino=16114 scontext=u:r:untrusted_app:s0:c183,c257,c512,c768 tcontext=u:object_r:qti_debugfs:s0 tclass=dir permissive=0
2020-02-10 10:38:36.369 29836-29894/com.example.part_time_job W/e.part_time_jo: Accessing hidden method Ljava/security/spec/ECParameterSpec;->setCurveName(Ljava/lang/String;)V (light greylist, reflection)
2020-02-10 10:38:36.391 29836-29894/com.example.part_time_job W/e.part_time_jo: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard;->getThreadPolicy()Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy; (light greylist, linking)
2020-02-10 10:38:36.391 29836-29894/com.example.part_time_job W/e.part_time_jo: Accessing hidden method Ldalvik/system/BlockGuard$Policy;->onNetwork()V (light greylist, linking)
2020-02-10 10:38:37.656 29836-29836/com.example.part_time_job E/RecyclerView: No adapter attached; skipping layout
2020-02-10 10:38:38.262 29836-29836/com.example.part_time_job E/Register4: Received an exception FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/part-time-job-74d92/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cmxwcm9qZWN0cy9wYXJ0LXRpbWUtam9iLTc0ZDkyL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9Kb2IgQXBwbGljYW50IERldGFpbHMvaW5kZXhlcy9DSUNBZ09qWGg0RUsQAhoKCgZlbXBVSUQQARoKCgZ1c2VySWQQARoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAB
2020-02-10 10:38:38.263 29836-29877/com.example.part_time_job W/Firestore: (21.3.1) [Firestore]: Listen for Query(target=Query( collectionGroup=Job Applicant Details where userId == uOQXpA8WSgWb5DeDqXxLsdEz0G22 and empUID == null order by __name__);limitType=LIMIT_TO_FIRST) failed: Status{code=FAILED_PRECONDITION, description=The query requires an index. You can create it here: https://console.firebase.google.com/v1/r/project/part-time-job-74d92/firestore/indexes?create_composite=Cmxwcm9qZWN0cy9wYXJ0LXRpbWUtam9iLTc0ZDkyL2RhdGFiYXNlcy8oZGVmYXVsdCkvY29sbGVjdGlvbkdyb3Vwcy9Kb2IgQXBwbGljYW50IERldGFpbHMvaW5kZXhlcy9DSUNBZ09qWGg0RUsQAhoKCgZlbXBVSUQQARoKCgZ1c2VySWQQARoMCghfX25hbWVfXxAB, cause=null}
2020-02-10 10:38:41.232 29836-29870/com.example.part_time_job V/FA: Inactivity, disconnecting from the service
```

**My Java Code**

```
package com.example.part_time_job;


import android.location.Address;
import android.os.Bundle;

import androidx.annotation.NonNull;
import androidx.fragment.app.Fragment;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.LinearLayoutManager;
import androidx.recyclerview.widget.RecyclerView;

import android.util.Log;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.widget.TextView;

import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnFailureListener;
import com.google.android.gms.tasks.OnSuccessListener;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseAuth;
import com.google.firebase.auth.FirebaseUser;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.CollectionReference;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.DocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.FirebaseFirestore;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QueryDocumentSnapshot;
import com.google.firebase.firestore.QuerySnapshot;

import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;

import model.FInalApplyNotification;
import model.Jobpost;
import ui.JournalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp;
import util.JournalApi;


/**
 * A simple {@link Fragment} subclass.
 */
public class HistoryFragment extends Fragment {

    private static final String TAG = "Register4";


    private FirebaseUser user;
    private FirebaseAuth firebaseAuth;
    private FirebaseAuth.AuthStateListener authStateListener;
    private FirebaseFirestore db = FirebaseFirestore.getInstance();
    private List<FInalApplyNotification> journalList;
    private String empid;
    private String title;
    private String currentUserId;







    private RecyclerView recyclerViewnotifyemp;
    private JournalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp journalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp;


    private CollectionReference collectionReference=db.collection("Employer");
    private TextView no_listnotifyemp;




    public HistoryFragment() {
        // Required empty public constructor
    }


    @Override
    public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, ViewGroup container,
                             Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        // Inflate the layout for this fragment
        View view=inflater.inflate(R.layout.fragment_history, container, false);
        firebaseAuth= FirebaseAuth.getInstance();
        user =firebaseAuth.getCurrentUser();

        no_listnotifyemp= view.findViewById(R.id.no_listnotifyemp);
        journalList=new ArrayList<>();

        recyclerViewnotifyemp=view.findViewById(R.id.recyclerViewnotifyemp);
        recyclerViewnotifyemp.setHasFixedSize(true);
        recyclerViewnotifyemp.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(getActivity()));


        currentUserId=JournalApi.getInstance().getUserId();





        return view;
    }

    @Override
    public void onStart() {
        super.onStart();
        if (journalList!=null){
            journalList.clear();
        }

        FInalApplyNotification fInalApplyNotification=new FInalApplyNotification();
        fInalApplyNotification.setTitle(title);
        fInalApplyNotification.setUserId(currentUserId);

                db.collectionGroup("Job Applicant Details").whereEqualTo("userId",currentUserId).whereEqualTo("empUID",fInalApplyNotification.getEmpUID())
                    .get()
                    .addOnSuccessListener(new OnSuccessListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
                        @Override
                        public void onSuccess(QuerySnapshot queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                            if (!queryDocumentSnapshots.isEmpty()) {
                                for (QueryDocumentSnapshot journals : queryDocumentSnapshots) {
                                    FInalApplyNotification fInalApplyNotification = journals.toObject(FInalApplyNotification.class);
                                    journalList.add(fInalApplyNotification);


                                }

                                journalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp = new JournalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp(getActivity(), journalList);
                                recyclerViewnotifyemp.setAdapter(journalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp);
                                journalRecyclerAdapterNotificationEmp.notifyDataSetChanged();


                            } else {

                                no_listnotifyemp.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);

                            }
                        }
                    })
                    .addOnFailureListener(new OnFailureListener() {
                        @Override
                        public void onFailure(@NonNull Exception e) {
                            Log.e(TAG, "Received an exception " + e.getMessage() );


                        }
                    });



    }




}
```

**My Query**

```
db.collectionGroup("Job Applicant Details").whereEqualTo("userId",currentUserId).whereEqualTo("empUID",fInalApplyNotification.getEmpUID())
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Firebase firestore have mainly 2 types of queries

1. [Simple queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#simple_queries)
2. [Compound queries](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/queries?authuser=1#compound_queries)

---

1. Simple queries have only where condition, so they don't need database indexes, like

```
FirebaseFirestore.getInstance().collection("cities")
        .whereEqualTo("capital", true)
        .get()
        .addOnCompleteListener(new OnCompleteListener<QuerySnapshot>() {
            @Override
            public void onComplete(@NonNull Task<QuerySnapshot> task) {
                if (task.isSuccessful()) {
                    for (QueryDocumentSnapshot document : task.getResult()) {
                        Log.d(TAG, document.getId() + " => " + document.getData());
                    }
                } else {
                    Log.d(TAG, "Error getting documents: ", task.getException());
                }
            }
        });
```

2. Your query is compound query which has multiple **Where** queries chained together which needs **[composite index](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=1)**, you can either create composite index in [firebase console](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=1#use_the_firebase_console) or create composite index using [error message](https://firebase.google.com/docs/firestore/query-data/indexing?authuser=1#create_a_missing_index_through_an_error_message), creating index using error message is easier one, which is printed in your log message, as it handles the fields and sorting order and directly creates index for you

Answer (score 1):

As the exception states, you must create an index for the query you are performing.

> FAILED_PRECONDITION: The query requires an index. You can create it here: {some link}

The link provided by the exception, when entered into a browser will load the Firebase Console with all the details you need to create the index needed for the query. So you just need to visit the link and follow the instructions.